# Как написать в TCP-сокет из консоли в POSIX-окружении?

Tags: tcp, sh, posix

Можно ли в *POSIX*-окружении, в `sh`, принять входящее
*TCP*-соединение, написать в него ответ (напирмер,
*HTTP*-ответ со статусом `200 OK`), и закрыть сокет?

Обязательно используя только утилиты, описанные в стандарте.  Иначе,
понятное дело, есть `nc`.  Суть вопроса в том, чтобы обойтись
только тем, что есть «из коробки».

Comment: Вопрос можно перефразировать в духе "есть ли в стандарте HTTP сервер"

Comment: Скорее, «есть ли в стандарте средства работы с *TCP* и *UDP* (где одно — там и другое) из консоли».

Comment: в posix — нет; в linux — тоже нет; в bash — есть клиент, сервера — нет... ЕМНИП в каком-то экзотическом варианте unix-like'а такое было, но сейчас что-то не могу вспомнить навскидку...

Comment: @Fat-Zer в каком-нибудь Plan9? Там всё было, только не взлетело :)